# How to view own story in snapchat

Tags: snapchat, social-networking-service

I'm not very good at SnapChat. Is there a way to view your own story? My friend helped me set a picture and now I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to view your own Story, follow the below steps :

1. Swipe left on the Camera screen to the Stories screen ;
2. Tap 'My Story,' or the circular icon of a Snap to the left of 'My Story.'

Source : [Snapchat support](https://support.snapchat.com/a/view-stories).

Comment: I forgot to mention I tried these instructions and they're non-sense. I swipe left and get to my received snaps. I swipe right and I get to everyone's stories, except mine. There is no "my story".

Comment: I don't know if it is possible, but maybe you could try to add yourself as friend and maybe you'll be able to see your own story.
Also have a look at this : http://visihow.com/Edit_Who_Can_Send_You_Snaps_and_View_Your_Story_on_SnapChat